# Print effect with CSS

Tags: jquery, css

[image]

Is it possible at all to achieve this effect with CSS3 (and maybe jQuery)? I tried the usual 'slideDown' effect but its not even close to this. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes it's possible, you have enough experience on this site to know by now that at least *some* effort on your part is expected. To be honest, it looks rather simple.

Comment: .. even though I can't figure where to start, and that itself is the question? Really, SO is getting worse lately, you just can't ask anything at all. :S

Comment: There are so many questions each day that if we don't filter out the crap, no one will want to participate. Bare minimum effort is all I'm saying. "*I tried the usual 'slideDown'...*" OK, there ya go - let's see what you tried.

Comment: Right, but is this one of them? I guess not, its a very valid question and put put nicely with an image example and I did mention about trying the slide effect, do you want me to make a jsfiddle for that?

Comment: You just posted a picture and said "how do i make this?". It's valid in the sense that it's technically a question (has a question mark).

Comment: I'm not a mod, just someone who enjoys this site very much and doesn't want to see it deteriorate into "here's picture, how to make?".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do it with CSS transitions..

The concept is to have an element with `height:0` and `overflow:hidden` (*lets name it paper-holder*)) and inside it an absolutely positioned element at the bottom (*with `bottom:0`*) (*paper*)

This way when you transition the height of the *paper-holder* element from 0 to the height of the *paper* it will seem like the paper is sliding out.

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/9FfKZ/1/

---

***Update***

An improvement to make the print steps more obvious, would be to use the `steps` (*[documentation](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-transitions/#transition-timing-function-property)*) timing function instead of the linear my initial demo had

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/9FfKZ/4/

Answer (score 7):

My thought one this is to have 3 different elements. Forget the paper for now. just consider the printer slot. I would make it into two separate images. The top have and the bottom half. The two images should meet where you want the paper to feed from. Position the two images absolutely so they look joined as normal.

The trick here will be in the `z-index` You want the top half to have a higher z-index than the lower half, essentially bringing it "closer to the user" on the z-axis. Make the top have have a `z-index:9999;` and the bottom half have a `z-index:9995;`

Now, you will want to create a div that represents the paper. Give that div a z-index: somewhere in between the top and bottom graphics, so give it a `z-index:9997;`. Position it absolutely behind the top graphics, and slowly animate it downward until its end point.

**Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XzVA9/2/**

---

**HTML**

```
<img id="top" src="http://s1.postimage.org/txsnx2v9r/imgtop.png" />
<div id="paper">Receipt</div>
<img id="bottom" src="http://s1.postimage.org/3o7lea9cf/imgbot.png" />
```

---

**CSS**

```
#top{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:9999;
}
#bottom{
    position:absolute;
    top:284px;
    left:0;
    z-index:9995;
}
#paper{
    position:absolute;
    top:204px;
    left:250px;
    z-index:9997;
    width:300px;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    padding:15px 0;
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid #999;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:22pt;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
            box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black; 
}
```

---

**JS**

```
$('#paper').animate({'top':'284px'}, 3000);​
```

---

Comment: 1 up for the walk through on the CSS layer of things, I think your answer and my answer combined will achieve the desired affect. Dutchie deserves the points for being more thorough though :-P

Comment: See working Demo link above

Comment: Looks like it took you less time to actually code it up than it took us to argue up there in the comments whether my question was valid or not. Thanks heaps, this is just perfect!

Comment: To be fair, your question is not valid. I happen to be bored and wanted to see if I could code it myself.

Comment: By the way, you could easily accomplish that animation with CSS3 transitions instead of the JQuery code.

Answer (score 0):

Use setInterval in javascript to set positions every x milliseconds, to create a jittery effect. Make sure that you have the appropriate CSS to make this work, ie. position absolute / relative on the right elements

```
var offset_y = 0,
    slide_interval = setInterval(function() {
        $('#element').css({
            left    : 0,
            top     : offset_y
        });

        offset_y += 2;

        if(offset_y > 1000) // Desired Value Here
            clearInterval(slide_interval);
    });
```

Comment: Animation with `setInterval` will never be smooth. See http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

Comment: That's the point... look at the GIF, it's not a smooth animation, hence my comment of creating a "jittery affect", thank you for down voting without reading

Comment: Sorry, can't undo unless you edit the answer.